# Why can't I use riak.conf in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, riak

I am trying to setup Riak on Ubuntu 14.04 just to learn something about it.

Right now I am trying to setup the backend of Riak with Bitcask since that is what is used by default.

The problem I am running into at the moment is when the instructions say "You can set Bitcask as the storage engine using each node's configuration files:". Then I see this:

**riak.conf** | app.config

storage_backend = bitcask

*http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/backends/bitcask/#Installing-Bitcask*

So I type "storage_backend = bitcask", but the terminal responded with "storage_backend: command not found". I tried "sudo storage_backend = bitcask", response was "sudo: storage_backend: command not found". Finally I tried "sudo bitcask.storage_backend = bitcask" and got "sudo: bitcask.storage_backend: command not found".

I've also gone to the Configuration Files webpage to view the other "riak.conf" tabs, and tried to type those into the terminal, but I still got the same "command not found" error.

So what am I doing wrong? Also, what is a ".conf" file, I can't seem to find a good explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation means that you should edit the file called `riak.conf` which is somewhere probably in `/etc/riak/riak.conf`, and add to this file:

```
storage_backend = bitcask
```

It's not a command, it is content that you should edit in the file riak.conf